# How to I get directive to run again on data load

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a directive that should check if a user has a claim and then display the corresponding menu element based on this.

```
  export class ClaimsDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private authorizationService: AuthorizationService
  ) { }

  @Input() set claims(allowedClaims: Array<string>) {
      let shouldShow: boolean = false;
      for (let allowedClaim of allowedClaims) {
        if (this.authorizationService.hasClaim(allowedClaim))
          shouldShow = true;
      }
      if (shouldShow) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      } else {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
      }
    }
}
```

This works just fine on a reload. But if I sign out it's not run. Whats the best way to get this to recheck on sign in/out?

EDIT: based on comments and some reading:

In authorization service I create a BehaviorSubject

```
  private isAuth: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  public getIsAuth(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isAuth.asObservable();
  }
```

Then in the constructor I check if you are logged in:

```
const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.currentUserKey));
if (currentUser)
  this.isAuth = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
else
  this.isAuth = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Then on login/logout:

```
this.isAuth.next(true);
```

And finally in the directive I subscribe:

```
this.authorizationService.getIsAuth().subscribe(v=> this.checkShouldShow());
```

Is this the correct pattern for Angular 5 /RxJS?

(this is based on answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/76inse/noob_observable_on_change_of_value/ )

Comment: authorizationService should expose an observable to watch for current auth state.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that sentence, maybe give me an example?

Comment: There should be something like isAuth$ observable that could be subscribed by units that depend on auth state changes (such as this directive). The way it should be done solely depends on how the service works.

Comment: Added a solution in with an edit, is this right?

Comment: Yes' that's how it's usually done. There's no reason for getIsAuth to be an function, it's just `isAuth$ = this.isAuth.asObservable()`. Notice that since isAuth is behavior subject, current value is also available as isAuth.value, in case it's ever needed.

Comment: Would you like to create an answer so I can give you points :)

Comment: Sure. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for other units to be notified of changes in auth state, auth service shoud expose an observable that can be subscribed:

```
private isAuth = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public isAuth$ = this.isAuth.asObservable();
```

It can emit state changes with `this.isAuth.next(...)`. Since `isAuth` is `BehaviorSubject`, current value is also available as `this.isAuth.value`.

Other units can subscribe to changes with:

```
authorizationService.isAuth$.subscribe(isAuth => { ... });
```